# How to check if any one of the element in the list displayed in protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor

I want to check if any one of the listed elements is displayed on the webpage using a protractor. I understand that to check the visibility of the element in the protractor we use `isDisplayed()` or `isPresent()`. But how to check if at least an element from the list of elements is `displayed`, in the protractor.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `findElements` which will return a list of web element if found at least 1 web element or more. if not it will not have anything and it's size will be zero.

Use it like this

```
const muchoCheese = driver.findElements(By.id('web element id should be given here')).count();
```

print the `muchoCheese` to get the number of elements.